# CEF - how to call callback c++ form JS-code

Tags: javascript, c++, chromium-embedded

How can I call a C++ function using JavaScript?

For example, I am executing js code in a browser window using the method `CefFrame::ExecuteJavaScript` like this:

```
(*frame).GetMainFrame()).ExecuteJavaScript("const elem = document.getElementsByClassName("my_class")[0];const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect(); alert(rect.x + \":\" + rect.y)", "", 1);
```

Is it possible to somehow call a C++ function for the place of the JS `alert()` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I call a c++ function from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101191/can-i-call-a-c-function-from-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in two ways. They are almost equal: you can create several native functions at once with `CefRegisterExtension`, and you can create a single native function with `CefV8Value::CreateFunction`. The example bellow is just a sketch, nowhere can test it, small issues are possible, but the idea is clear:

```cpp
class MyAlertHandler : public CefV8Handler {
 public:
  bool Execute(const CefString& name,
               CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object,
               const CefV8ValueList& arguments,
               CefRefPtr<CefV8Value>& retval,
               CefString& exception) override {
    if (!arguments.empty()) {
      // arguments[0]->GetStringValue();
    }
    return true;
  }
};

CefRefPtr<CefV8Handler> handler = new MyAlertHandler;

CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> v8_context = frame->GetMainFrame()->GetV8Context();
if (v8_context.get() && v8_context->Enter()) {
  CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> global = v8_context->GetGlobal();
  CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> my_alert = CefV8Value::CreateFunction("my_alert", handler);
  global->SetValue("my_alert", my_alert, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);
  v8_context->Exit();
}
```

Calling `Enter()` and `Exit()` on a V8 context can be omitted if `CefV8Value::CreateFunction` is called from `CefRenderProcessHandler` functions.

```cpp
frame->GetMainFrame()->ExecuteJavaScript(R"(
  const elem = document.getElementsByClassName("my_class")[0];
  const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  my_alert(rect.x + ":" + rect.y);)", "", 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! But nothing works:(

Comment: everything is fully compiled. But nothing happens or I misunderstood something. But I put a breakpoint in MyAlertHandler - and it never gets there.

Comment: Do you know that this code runs in the renderer process, have you enabled multiproces debugging in visual studio?

Comment: I run this code in the OnContextCreated() callback of the render process (CefRenderProcessHandler).

Comment: I also thought so, and therefore, for verification, I just did it - I put simple std::cout<<"MyAlertHandler" in MyAlertHandler; But it didn't work either.

Comment: why ?? why does std::cout - not work ? At least in OnContextCreated() - it works.

Comment: If std::cout - does not work, then the rest of the C++ code will not work either. Then what 's the point ?

Comment: I've update the code. It had errors. You should have fixed it, but you haven't show your fix, thus I don't know how your code looks like and if you have fixed it correctly.